Mini-map fragment not showing the location taken from a previous activity
I have the following values taken from the previous activity to display in the following code below:
Scenario:
Emergency Type:
Specific location markers, if any

and the location of the selected user off a listview



 private GoogleMap mMap;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 99;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_emergency_details);

        // Receive data from intent extras
        String scenarioData = getIntent().getStringExtra("Scenario");
        String emergencyTypeData = getIntent().getStringExtra("Emergency Type");
        latitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("Latitude", 0.0);
        longitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("Longitude", 0.0);

        // Find TextViews for scenario data and emergency type
        TextView tvScenarioData = findViewById(R.id.tvScenario);
        TextView tvEmergencyTypeData = findViewById(R.id.tvEmergencyType);

        // Set text for scenario data and emergency type TextViews
        tvScenarioData.setText(scenarioData);
        tvEmergencyTypeData.setText(emergencyTypeData);

        // Check and request location permission if needed
        checkLocationPermission();

        // Initialize SupportMapFragment and handle map customization
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.miniMapFragment);
        if (mapFragment != null) {
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error loading map!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        Log.d("EmergencyDetails", "Received Latitude: " + latitude);
        Log.d("EmergencyDetails", "Received Longitude: " + longitude);
    }

    private void checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission already granted
            // Proceed with map initialization or other location-dependent tasks
            initializeMap();
        } else {
            // Request location permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    private void initializeMap() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (mMap != null) {
                try {
                    // Add marker to the map if latitude and longitude are valid
                    LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 15f));
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    Log.e("MapError", "Error enabling location on map: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Map is not ready yet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Location permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Location permission granted, initialize the map
                initializeMap();
            } else {
                // Location permission denied, handle accordingly
                Toast.makeText(this, "Location permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission already granted, initialize the map
            initializeMap();
        } else {
            // Request location permission if not granted
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
}

The location data is being retrieved from Firebase through a previous activity via Intents, however, when on the current activity, it does not display the location retrieved. Please do note, that the Maps feature is set up correctly for this project, as it is already being used in other activities but is working properly.
Here is the logcat:
09:20:47.949  D  Received Latitude: 120.7152931
09:20:47.949  D  Received Longitude: 15.4487153

This is how the location data is being retrieved from the previous activity:
DatabaseReference selectedUserLocationRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                                .getReference().child("User Location").child(selectedUid);
                        selectedUserLocationRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot locationSnapshot) {
                                if (locationSnapshot.exists()) {
                                    Double latitude = locationSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                                    Double longitude = locationSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
                                    if (latitude != null && longitude != null) {
                                                // Data retrieved successfully, now start the new activity
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(LocationLog.this, EmergencyDetails.class);
                                        intent.putExtra("Emergency Type", model.getEmergencyType());
                                        intent.putExtra("Scenario", model.getScenario());
                                        intent.putExtra("Latitude", latitude);
                                        intent.putExtra("Longitude", longitude);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                            }
                                    else {
                                        // Handle missing location data
                                        Log.e(TAG, "Latitude or Longitude is null");
                                            }
                                        }
                                else {
                                    // Handle if the location data for the selected user doesn't exist
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Location data does not exist for UID: " + selectedUid);
                                        }

                                    }


That's not a valid latitude 120.7152931 - valid range is [-90.0, 90.0] did lat/lon perhaps get swapped at some point, on the intent sender side?

I've always been retrieving and sending location with these coordinates.

That's OK - but again a latitude of 120.7152931 is not valid (and that is what your log statement shows) and would be ignored by maps.  If swapped (lat=15.4487153, lon=120.7152931) they would be a point near Manilla Phillipines.

Let me edit my question to include how the location is being retrieved.

Also include the code which saves it in firebase - it will ultimately be a simple error but what is posted so far has no error - if helpful add logcats where you save and retrieve.
Or just look at your firebase and verify the values.

I've checked the code and you're correct, it is being flipped. I will try sending another location to see if it fixes the issue.

As stated in the comments, I've double-checked how the location is being sent to Firebase and can see that the values for latitude and longitude are being flipped:
Previous code:
private void saveLocationToFirebase(double latitude, double longitude) {
    // Clear existing markers
    mMap.clear();
    // Add marker for the user's current location
    LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude); // Latitude and longitude swapped here
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("Current Location"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLocation, 15f));
    // Save location data to Firebase
    LocationSend locationSend = new LocationSend(latitude, longitude);
    reference.setValue(locationSend);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Location sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

Updated code:
private void saveLocationToFirebase(double latitude, double longitude) {
    // Clear existing markers
    mMap.clear();
    // Add marker for the user's current location
    LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(longitude, latitude); // Correct order: longitude, latitude
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("Current Location"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLocation, 15f));
    // Save location data to Firebase
    LocationSend locationSend = new LocationSend(latitude, longitude); // Correct order: latitude, longitude
    reference.setValue(locationSend);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Location sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

I've also updated the overall code where the location values are being read/written.
